# What happens to a node when it is unlinked in a LinkedList in java?

Tags: java

What happen to a node in a LinkedList, when you unlink a node from the linkedList in java? I seem to be unavailable to find this answer. NOTE: the node is not manually deleted. But only deferenced.

Comment: what do you mean by unlink (if the object is not referenced any more it will removed by GC ) please post your code

Comment: If there is no reference to the object, Garbage Collector will remove it.